# Python connect MSSql

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I am trying to connect `AWS` `MSSQL` database, I tried many different ways to connect but I got every time an error.

Here are my codes and errors

```
    import pyodbc
    server = 'mssqlins.abcdefghklmn.us-north-2.rds.amazonaws.com'
    database = 'database'
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

    sql = """SELECT * FROM dbo.member;"""

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    Error: ('01000', u"[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL SERVER' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

The second:

```
    server = 'mssqlins.abcdefghklmn.us-north-2.rds.amazonaws.com'
    driver = 'SQL+Server'
    db = 'database'
    myQuery = '''SELECT * FROM deneme'''
    engine = sql.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://{}/{}?driver={}'.format(server, db, driver))
    df = pd.read_sql_query(myQuery, engine)
--------------------------------------------------------------------

  DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', u"[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)") (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)
```

The Third

```
ServerName ='mssqlins.abcdefghklmn.us-north-2.rds.amazonaws.com' 
Database = 'database' 
TableName = 'deneme'

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://' + ServerName + '/' + Database)
conn = engine.connect()
-----------------------------------------------------------

InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', u'[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
```

I do not know what is my connection problem. I am trying to connect AWS Mssql database and I can see data in an SQL ide.

How can I read Mssql code in Python?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the MSSQL ODBC driver for pyodbc, you can download the driver from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server

Comment: I am using a mac and I have iODBC but I do not know which drivers should be in, Do you have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Mac-OSX

Comment: Regarding using pyodbc with iODBC, a speaker of the iODBC maintainers has said this: "We (OpenLink Software -- maintainers of iODBC since the 1990s, vendor of ODBC drivers and various other products, and my employer) would like to help you get pyodbc built and working properly with the macOS-native iODBC would like to help you get pyodbc built and working properly with the macOS-native iODBC" Ref: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/322